# TinyMCE Html editor in Umbraco stopped working

Tags: html, editor, tinymce, umbraco

The `TinyMCE` html editor has stopped showing up in my umbraco installtion.
If clicked the html button opens new popup but the content is never loaded.

Chrome gives me:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): 
    The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

The IIS log gives:

```
GET /umbraco_client/tinymce3/themes/umbraco/source_editor.htm 
    - 80 - 79.211.65.86 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/534.30+
    (KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/12.0.742.100+Safari/534.30 200 0 0
```

My experiments showed that content ending in .txt in the same directory is correctly served.
I suspect some kind of error with the rewrite rules.

What I tried:

- Added ~/umbraco_client/ to umbracoReservedPaths
- Renamed source_editor.htm to .aspx

Greatly appreciate any help and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. A http_handler for static content was needed. After I added the following to the web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
<add path="*.htm" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="True" />
```

The static .htm files are being served. Microsoft has a nice article on that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909641

Answer (score 0):

Could be some sort of IIS URL rewriting or caching going on.

Does anything change if you deactivate caching and url rewriting off?
And what are the contents of your web.config and UrlRewriting.config files regarding rewriting and caching?